# Prove or disprove formally: $(\forall x F) \lor G \vDash \forall x (F \lor G)$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I want to formally prove that this statement is either false or true. I think it is false, because $G$ could contain the variable $x$ unbound and for some interpretation $\mathcal A$, $G$ could be true for some $x$ while $(\forall x G)$ is false and $(\forall x F)$ is false. So $(\forall x F) \lor G$ evaluates to true, while $\forall x (F \lor G)$ evaluates to false, so $(\forall x F) \lor G \nvDash \forall x (F \lor G)$ for the same interpretation $\mathcal A$.

However, I am in doubt if my reasoning is correct and I do not know how to prove this formally.

Comment: Well, if you think it's false, can you give an *explicit* counterexample?

Comment: Let the universe $U=\mathbb Z$ then $(\forall x (x<0)) \lor (y>x)$, for $x=1, y=2$ this is true but  $(\forall x ((x<0)) \lor (y>x))$ is false because $x=2$ is a counterexample and hence it is not a logical consequence.

Comment: @david Correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that in your system, formulas with free variables can be assigned a truth value relative to an assignment function, you are correct with your suspicion that $G$ could be true of one object but not another.

Suppose $F$ has a free variable, $F(x)$, and $G$ has a free variable, $G(x)$. Consider the counter model $\mathcal{M} = \langle D, \mathcal{I} \rangle$ with $D = \{a, b\}, \mathcal{I}(F) = \emptyset, \mathcal{I}(G) = \{a\}$ and assignment function $v : x \mapsto a$.

Then, since $v(x) = a \in \mathcal{I}(G)$, we have that $\mathcal{M}, v \vDash G(x)$, so $\mathcal{M}, v \vDash (\forall x F(x)) \lor G(x)$.
But since $b \not \in \mathcal{I}(F)$ and $b \not \in \mathcal{I}(G)$, it holds for the assignment variant $v'$ of $v$ with $v': x \mapsto b$ that $\mathcal{M}, v' \not \vDash F(x) \lor G(x)$, hence $\mathcal{M}, v \not \vDash \forall x (F(x) \lor G(x))$.
Since there are formula instances, a structure and an assignment function such that the premise formula is true but the conclusion is not, the inference scheme does not hold.

Answer (score 0):

In the statement $(\forall x F) \vee G$, $G$ is not within the scope of a quantifier on $x$. That means that, if this is a sentence which can be evaluated as "true" or "false", $G$ must not include $x$. Which means that when you put a quantifier on $x$ in front of it, as in $(\forall x)G$, the result is counterintuitive - the quantifier has no effect!

As a simple example, $G$ might be "the sky is blue". $(\forall x)G$ would then be "no matter what $x$ is, the sky is blue". But whether or not the sky is blue doesn't depend on which object is named "$x$", so $(\forall x)G$ is true exactly when $G$ is.

I would recommend, for this one, thinking about what happens for a particular $x$, say $a$. Suppose that $(\forall x F) \vee G$ is true. Can you show that $F(a) \vee G$ is true? If so, since $a$ was chosen arbitrarily, it must be that $(\forall x)(F \vee G)$ is true.

Comment: But $G$ could contain the variable $x$ unbound. Say $x$ is the temperature in Celsius and for the sake of this exmaple the sky can only be blue if the temperature is above 30 degrees and $G$ is the statement "the sky is blue" and $F$ is also the statement "the sky is blue". If $x=31$ then $G$ is true, but $F$ is false, because the statement is not true for every temperature.

Comment: @david You should double-check your textbook's definition of a "sentence". In most systems, a "sentence" is a well-formed formula *with no free variables*. In particular, if $G$ includes the variable $x$ unbound, then the formula "$(\forall xF) \vee G$" is not a sentence and does not have a truth value. In some systems I've read, an unbound variable is treated as an implicit universal quantifier. I don't recall any where it's treated as an unknown constant. Think about the sense of it - if $x = 31$, then what does "for all $x$" mean?

Comment: @Reese Plenty textbooks do let formulas with free variables have truth values, by defining the truth value of formulas relative to a model as well as an assignment function which maps variables to objects in the domain. Logical entailment then requires truth to be preserved under all models and assignment functions; in this case the presence of a free variable in $G$ may indeed lead to a counter example.

Comment: @lemontree I've seen that sometimes, but my recollection was that only sentences (with no free variables) were permitted for deductions (as in, $\varphi \vDash \psi$ only makes sense if $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are sentences). I could be wrong on that, it's been a long time since I read any of those books.

Comment: Every book does it differently, but it is certainly possible to define it that way: $\Gamma \vDash \phi$ iff for all structures $\mathcal{M}$ and all assignment functions $v$: If $\mathcal{M}, v \vDash \psi$ for all $\psi \in \Gamma$, then $\mathcal{M}, v \vDash \phi$. The point being that the implicit universal quantification over the free variables ranges over the whole entailment, rather than just the individual formulas.

Comment: But sure, it may well be that the OP's textbook assumes the variant with only sentences, in which your answer is correct, so they should check what definition is being used.

Comment: My textbook does not at all define a sentence. It only defines the syntax, the semantics and the interpretation of a formula. That is it. My textbook explicitly states that the same variable may occur bound and free in a formula. An interpretation is suitable if it defines all variables that occur freely (among other things). So with those definitions, is my reasoning to the question above correct?

Comment: @david In this case, your solution is perfectly correct. (I only saw it after I had already written my answer.)